# Bootstrap buttons not aligned in one row when view expanded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 7 buttons in one row, when I expand the view, they all together take only half the view.

I want the buttons in one row and expand with the view expand.

Also, the "offset-1" takes so much space, I want it less.

The full code here https://codepen.io/tarekhassab/pen/ZMajop?editors=1000

```
<div class='container'>
<button type="button"  value="" class='btn btn-primary'> All news </button>
<button type="button" value="Technology" class='offset-1 btn btn-primary'> Technology </button>
<button type="button"  value="Business" class='offset-1 btn btn-primary'> Business </button>
<button type="button"  value="Science" class='btn btn-primary'> Science </button>
<button type="button"  value="Entertainment" class='btn btn-primary'> Entertainment </button>
<button type="button"  value="Health" class='btn btn-primary'> Health </button>
<button type="button"  value="Sports" class='btn btn-primary'> Sports </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `text-center`

```
<div class='container text-center'>
<button type="button"  value="" class='btn btn-primary'> All news </button>
<button type="button" value="Technology" class='offset-1 btn btn-primary'> Technology </button>
<button type="button"  value="Business" class='offset-1 btn btn-primary'> Business </button>
<button type="button"  value="Science" class='btn btn-primary'> Science </button>
<button type="button"  value="Entertainment" class='btn btn-primary'> Entertainment </button>
<button type="button"  value="Health" class='btn btn-primary'> Health </button>
<button type="button"  value="Sports" class='btn btn-primary'> Sports </button>
</div>
```